# Index JSON field to be used in JSONPath comparison expression

Tags: postgresql, indexing, jsonb, jsonpath

Given the PostgreSQL 13.3 table and data

```sql
CREATE TABLE transaction (message jsonb NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO transaction(message) VALUES ('{"amount": 1.00}'), ('{"amount": 2.00}');
```

the index

```sql
CREATE INDEX ON transaction (((message->'amount')::numeric));
```

is used in the query

```sql
SELECT t.message FROM transaction t
WHERE (t.message->'amount')::numeric > 1.00;
```

Neither of the indexes

```sql
CREATE INDEX ON transaction USING GIN (message);
CREATE INDEX ON transaction USING GIN (message jsonb_path_ops);
```

is used in the query

```sql
SELECT t.message FROM transaction t
WHERE t.message @@ format('$.amount > %s', 1.00)::jsonpath;
```

Is there a way in PostgreSQL to index the `transaction.message` column so the JSONPath `@@` operator uses the index instead of doing a Seq Scan?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't have enough rows in the table for the index to be used. Either disable sequential scan for the session or try this

```
CREATE TABLE transaction (message jsonb NOT NULL);
INSERT INTO transaction(message) VALUES ('{"amount": 1.00}'), ('{"amount": 2.00}');
INSERT INTO transaction (message) SELECT ('{"amount": '|| random() * 100 || '}')::jsonb FROM generate_series(1, 1000);
CREATE INDEX ON transaction (((message->'amount')::numeric));
```

Now the index is used

```
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT t.message-> 'amount' FROM transaction t WHERE (t.message->'amount')::numeric = 1.00;
```

Returns

```
Bitmap Heap Scan on transaction t  (cost=4.31..12.41 rows=5 width=32) (actual time=0.260..0.328 rows=1 loops=1)
  Recheck Cond: (((message -> 'amount'::text))::numeric = 1.00)
  Heap Blocks: exact=1
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on transaction_numeric_idx  (cost=0.00..4.31 rows=5 width=0) (actual time=0.226..0.237 rows=1 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (((message -> 'amount'::text))::numeric = 1.00)
Planning Time: 0.131 ms
Execution Time: 0.448 ms
```

It still chooses sequential scan for

```
SELECT t.message-> 'amount' FROM transaction t WHERE (t.message->'amount')::numeric > 1.00
```

Possibly because the planner sees too many values > 1.00 in the statistics.

For the second part of the question

```
CREATE INDEX ON transaction USING GIN (message jsonb_path_ops);
EXPLAIN ANALYZE SELECT t.message FROM transaction t WHERE t.message @@ '$.amount == 1.00';
```

Returns

```
Bitmap Heap Scan on transaction t  (cost=8.01..12.02 rows=1 width=36) (actual time=0.103..0.141 rows=1 loops=1)
  Recheck Cond: (message @@ '($.""amount"" == 1.00)'::jsonpath)"
  Heap Blocks: exact=1
  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on transaction_message_idx  (cost=0.00..8.01 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.051..0.061 rows=1 loops=1)
        Index Cond: (message @@ '($.""amount"" == 1.00)'::jsonpath)"
Planning Time: 0.120 ms
Execution Time: 0.227 ms
```

So this index will be used when it can, notably, in this case the jsonpath being `t.message @@ '$.amount == 1.00'`.

As @Bergi points out in the comment below, the second part of the question asked specifically about `t.message @@ '$.amount > 1.00'`. I can't pretend I know for sure, but I have a feeling the index only stores information about paths, meaning the things that are explicitly there, and doesn't help with comparisons of this sort. But that is just a guess. I did not see it used for anything other than `==`.

Comment: I think the question was asking about `t.message @@ '$.amount > 1.00'` not `message @@ '($.amount == 1.00)'`

Comment: Good catch. Unfortunately, I can't address this part fully. I added what I could.